# How to select a rectangle of the screen to capture by dragging mouse on transparent background with wxPython?

Tags: python, ffmpeg, wxpython

I'm working on building an application to capture screen with ffmpeg and would like to determine the portion of the screen to capture by dragging the mouse, drawing a rectangle and passing the arguments to the ffmpeg call.

I'm using wxPython to build a simple GUI for the application. I've gotten to the point where I can draw the rectangle and get the coordinates that I want: offset and size of the selected area.

```py
import wx

global selectionOffset, selectionSize

selectionOffset = ""
selectionSize = ""

class SelectableFrame(wx.Frame):

    c1 = None
    c2 = None

    def __init__(self, parent=None, id=wx.ID_ANY, title=""):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, parent, id, title, size=wx.DisplaySize(), style=wx.TRANSPARENT_WINDOW)

        self.Bind(wx.EVT_MOTION, self.OnMouseMove)
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_LEFT_DOWN, self.OnMouseDown)
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_LEFT_UP, self.OnMouseUp)
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_PAINT, self.OnPaint)

        self.SetCursor(wx.Cursor(wx.CURSOR_CROSS))

    def OnMouseMove(self, event):
        if event.Dragging() and event.LeftIsDown():
            self.c2 = event.GetPosition()
            self.Refresh()

    def OnMouseDown(self, event):
        self.c1 = event.GetPosition()

    def OnMouseUp(self, event):
        self.SetCursor(wx.Cursor(wx.CURSOR_ARROW))
        self.Destroy()

    def OnPaint(self, event):
        global selectionOffset, selectionSize
        if self.c1 is None or self.c2 is None: return

        dc = wx.PaintDC(self)
        dc.SetPen(wx.Pen('red', 1))
        dc.SetBrush(wx.Brush(wx.Colour(0, 0, 0), wx.TRANSPARENT))

        dc.DrawRectangle(self.c1.x, self.c1.y, self.c2.x - self.c1.x, self.c2.y - self.c1.y)
        selectionOffset = str(self.c1.x) + "x" + str(self.c1.y)
        selectionSize = str(abs(self.c2.x - self.c1.x)) + "x" + str(abs(self.c2.y - self.c1.y))
    def PrintPosition(self, pos):
        return str(pos.x) + "x" + str(pos.y)


class MyApp(wx.App):

    def OnInit(self):
        frame = SelectableFrame()
        frame.Show(True)
        self.SetTopWindow(frame)

        return True


app = MyApp(redirect=False)
app.MainLoop()
print("offset: " + selectionOffset + ". Screen selection size: " + selectionSize)
```

The problem is I can't get the "background" to be transparent so I can see which portion of the screen I'm really grabbing. How can I do that with wxPython? If there's an easier way with another GUI tool or python module I'm open to suggestions. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've never been clear as to why this is but you do have to allow the window to "setup" before you can access the transparency option.
In the following, I have included a menu option to toggle transparency on and off (0 is totally transparent and 255 is totally opaque).
I have also included a `wx.CallLater` to set the transparency upon start-up.

```
import wx

global selectionOffset, selectionSize

selectionOffset = ""
selectionSize = ""

class SelectableFrame(wx.Frame):

    c1 = None
    c2 = None

    def __init__(self, parent=None, id=wx.ID_ANY, title=""):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, parent, id, title, size=wx.DisplaySize())
        self.menubar = wx.MenuBar(wx.MB_DOCKABLE)
        self.filem = wx.Menu()
        self.filem.Append(wx.ID_EXIT, '&Transparency')
        self.menubar.Append(self.filem, '&File')
        self.SetMenuBar(self.menubar)
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_MOTION, self.OnMouseMove)
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_LEFT_DOWN, self.OnMouseDown)
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_LEFT_UP, self.OnMouseUp)
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_PAINT, self.OnPaint)
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_MENU, self.OnTrans)

        self.SetCursor(wx.Cursor(wx.CURSOR_CROSS))
        self.Show()
        self.transp = False
        wx.CallLater(250, self.OnTrans, None)

    def OnTrans(self, event):
        if self.transp == False:
            self.SetTransparent(180)
            self.transp = True
        else:
            self.SetTransparent(255)
            self.transp = False

    def OnMouseMove(self, event):
        if event.Dragging() and event.LeftIsDown():
            self.c2 = event.GetPosition()
            self.Refresh()

    def OnMouseDown(self, event):
        self.c1 = event.GetPosition()

    def OnMouseUp(self, event):
        self.SetCursor(wx.Cursor(wx.CURSOR_ARROW))
        self.Destroy()

    def OnPaint(self, event):
        global selectionOffset, selectionSize
        if self.c1 is None or self.c2 is None: return

        dc = wx.PaintDC(self)
        dc.SetPen(wx.Pen('red', 1))
        dc.SetBrush(wx.Brush(wx.Colour(0, 0, 0), wx.TRANSPARENT))

        dc.DrawRectangle(self.c1.x, self.c1.y, self.c2.x - self.c1.x, self.c2.y - self.c1.y)
        selectionOffset = str(self.c1.x) + "x" + str(self.c1.y)
        selectionSize = str(abs(self.c2.x - self.c1.x)) + "x" + str(abs(self.c2.y - self.c1.y))
    def PrintPosition(self, pos):
        return str(pos.x) + "x" + str(pos.y)


class MyApp(wx.App):

    def OnInit(self):
        frame = SelectableFrame()

        return True


app = MyApp(redirect=False)
app.MainLoop()
print("offset: " + selectionOffset + ". Screen selection size: " + selectionSize)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the answer. This was very helpful! Now I'm struggling trying to find a way to show the captured area while recording the screen. Any suggestions on how to do that? I've had partial success with screendc but it keeps "glitching" when the screen refreshes and I feel this is not the best approach.

Comment: On Windows or Mac `from PIL import ImageGrab` or see https://www.blog.pythonlibrary.org/2010/04/16/how-to-take-a-screenshot-of-your-wxpython-app-and-print-it/