# wxPython: Drawing on top of a GenStaticBitmap

Tags: python, wxpython, wxwidgets

I would like to take a screenshot of my monitor and draw a box on it by clicking and dragging my mouse. In order to listen to mouse events, I use `GenStaticBitmap` from `wx.lib.statbmp` instead of just `StaticBitmap`. This is the code I have so far for my "drawing window" class:

```
def __init__(self, parent = None, id=wx.ID_ANY):
    wx.Frame.__init__(self, parent, id, size = wx.DisplaySize())

    #Grab a screenshot and create GenStaticBitmap with it
    with mss() as sct:
        monitor = sct.monitors[1]
        img = sct.grab(monitor)
        width, height = img.size
    img = Image.frombytes("RGB", img.size, img.bgra, "raw", "BGRX")
    img = wx.Bitmap.FromBuffer(width, height, img.tobytes())
    self.bmp = wxbmp.GenStaticBitmap(self, ID=wx.ID_ANY, bitmap=img)

    self.bmp.Bind(wx.EVT_LEFT_DOWN, self.on_mouse_click)
    self.bmp.Bind(wx.EVT_MOTION, self.on_move)
    self.bmp.Bind(wx.EVT_LEFT_UP, self.exit)
    self.bmp.Bind(wx.EVT_PAINT, self.OnPaint)
    self.Bind(wx.EVT_KEY_DOWN, self.exit)

    self.ShowFullScreen(True)

    self.SetCursor(wx.Cursor(wx.CURSOR_CROSS))

def OnPaint(self, event):
    if self.p1 is None or self.p2 is None: 
        return
    dc = wx.PaintDC(self.bmp)
    dc.SetPen(wx.Pen('red', 1))
    dc.SetBrush(wx.TRANSPARENT_BRUSH)
    dc.DrawRectangle(self.p1.x, self.p1.y, self.p2.x - self.p1.x, self.p2.y - self.p1.y)

def on_mouse_click(self, event):
    self.p1 = event.GetPosition()

def on_move(self, event):
    if event.Dragging() and event.LeftIsDown():
        self.p2 = event.GetPosition()
        self.bmp.Refresh()

def exit(self, event):
    self.Destroy()
```

which was adapted from [How to select a rectangle of the screen to capture by dragging mouse on transparent background with wxPython?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57342753/how-to-select-a-rectangle-of-the-screen-to-capture-by-dragging-mouse-on-transpar).

The problem is that every rectangle drawn to the screen remains trailing behind the current rectangle, on top of the fact that the fill of the rectangle seems to be black instead of transparent. If I do `dc.Clear()`, that fixes the drawing, but gets rid of the underlying bitmap. This code works fine if I'm simply drawing to a frame without a bitmap. I have tried using `wx.MemoryDC([my bitmap])`, drawing in there, then doing `self.bmp.SetBitmap([my bitmap])` in `OnPaint()`, but that doesn't seem to be working at all. Any advice is appreciated!

Comment: why not use wxOverlay? What's wx version and platform you are testing on?

Comment: @Igor Wow, thanks. I didn't really know about wxOverlay -- it works well, thank you very much! Printing wx.version() yields "4.1.1 msw (phoenix) wxWidgets 3.1.5" and I'm on Windows 10. I will post an answer with the updated code.

Answer (score 0):

Big thanks to [Igor](https://stackoverflow.com/users/945871/igor). The following is the new "drawing window" class, which seems to be working well.

```
def __init__(self, parent=None, id=wx.ID_ANY):
    wx.Frame.__init__(self, parent, id, size=wx.DisplaySize())

    #Grab a screenshot and create GenStaticBitmap with it
    with mss() as sct:
        monitor = sct.monitors[1]
        img = sct.grab(monitor)
        width, height = img.size
    img = Image.frombytes("RGB", img.size, img.bgra, "raw", "BGRX")
    img = wx.Bitmap.FromBuffer(width, height, img.tobytes())
    self.bmp = wxbmp.GenStaticBitmap(self, ID=wx.ID_ANY, bitmap=img)
    self.overlay = wx.Overlay()

    self.bmp.Bind(wx.EVT_LEFT_DOWN, self.on_mouse_click)
    self.bmp.Bind(wx.EVT_MOTION, self.on_move)
    self.bmp.Bind(wx.EVT_LEFT_UP, self.exit)
    self.Bind(wx.EVT_KEY_DOWN, self.exit)

    self.ShowFullScreen(True)

    self.SetCursor(wx.Cursor(wx.CURSOR_CROSS))

def on_mouse_click(self, event):
    self.p1 = event.GetPosition()

def on_move(self, event):
    if event.Dragging() and event.LeftIsDown():
        self.p2 = event.GetPosition()
        
        dc = wx.ClientDC(self.bmp)
        odc = wx.DCOverlay(self.overlay, dc)
        odc.Clear()

        dc.SetPen(wx.Pen('red', 1))
        dc.SetBrush(wx.TRANSPARENT_BRUSH)
        dc.DrawRectangle(self.p1.x, self.p1.y, self.p2.x - self.p1.x, self.p2.y - self.p1.y)
        

def exit(self, event):
    self.Destroy()
```